# Problems mailing multiple files via android app

Tags: android, email, android-intent, email-attachments, android-sdcard

I made an android app and to help me with debugging I put in a little program that would write session logs in a file and then store that file in the sdcard. I wanted to go one step further with this and implement backup and deletion of the files so created. I implemented the deletion part but I can't seem to figure out how to email these files to myself. I have looked at other similar questions here and this  is the code that I have right now,

```
    private void BackupAndClearDirectory(){
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Music/");
    if(f.isDirectory() && f.exists()) Log.i("MyActivity", f.getAbsolutePath()+" exists");
    File [] files = f.listFiles();
    if(files == null){
        Log.i("MyActivity",f.getAbsolutePath()+" doesn't contain files");
        return;
    }
   // else Log.i("MyActivity","Directory doesn't exist");
    final int MAXFILEAGE = 7200000; //Max file age is 2 hrs

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Mail");

    String[] fileList;
    fileList = new String[1000];
    fileList = f.list();
    if(fileList == null || fileList.length == 0) Log.i("MyActivity","Empty filelist");
      /*for(File fl : files){
        long lastModified = fl.lastModified();
        if(lastModified + MAXFILEAGE<System.currentTimeMillis())
        {
            fileList.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/"+fl.getName());
            //Log.i("MyActivity","Deleting file "+fl);
            //files[i].delete();
        }
    }*/

   // fileList.add(files[0].toString());
   // fileList.add(files[1].toString());

    Log.i("MyActivity","List of files created");

    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
   //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's

    for (int i=0;i<fileList.length;i++)
    {
        File fileIn = new File(fileList[i]);
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
        uris.add(u);
    }

    Log.i("MyActivity","List of uris created");

    emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    con.startActivity(emailIntent);
 }
```

Everytime i try to run this, my app crashes and I get a NullPointerException. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Logcat output:

11-14 16:21:49.823  19014-19014/com.example.abhishek.deletiontesterapp I/MyActivity﹕ /storage/emulated/0/Music exists

11-14 16:21:49.823  19014-19014/com.example.abhishek.deletiontesterapp I/MyActivity﹕ /storage/emulated/0/Music doesn't contain files

It works when I hardcode the path to files, here's the code with hardcoded paths:

```
    private void BackupAndClearDirectory(){
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Music/");
    /*if(f.isDirectory() && f.exists()) Log.i("MyActivity", f.getAbsolutePath()+" exists");
    File [] files = f.listFiles();
    if(files == null){
        Log.i("MyActivity",f.getAbsolutePath()+" doesn't contain files");
        return;
    }
   // else Log.i("MyActivity","Directory doesn't exist");
    final int MAXFILEAGE = 7200000; //Max file age is 2 hrs
   */
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Mail");

    ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //if(fileList == null || fileList.length == 0) Log.i("MyActivity","Empty filelist");
      /*for(File fl : files){
        long lastModified = fl.lastModified();
        if(lastModified + MAXFILEAGE<System.currentTimeMillis())
        {
            fileList.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/"+fl.getName());
            //Log.i("MyActivity","Deleting file "+fl);
            //files[i].delete();
        }
    }*/

   fileList.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Music/1.txt");
   fileList.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Music/2.txt");
   // fileList.add(files[1].toString());

    Log.i("MyActivity","List of files created");

    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's

    for (int i=0;i<fileList.size();i++)
    {
        File fileIn = new File(fileList.get(i));
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
        uris.add(u);
    }

    Log.i("MyActivity","List of uris created");

    emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    con.startActivity(emailIntent);
 }
```

Comment: Which line causes this NullPointerExceptio? Look in the LogCat: it will tell you. Please post the logcat.

Comment: Your 'files' come from directory `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Download"` But you add `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Failures/"+fl.getName()` to the list. That makes no sense.

Comment: @greenapps: I have edited that. 
Also I found out that the problem is with the line listfiles(). I used a check files == null and it returned true. Since files is already null accessing its elements is giving nullpointerexception.
Can't figure out why files = f.listfiles() is failing. I have confirmed that f is a directory as can be seen in the code.

Comment: You still have not edited it here. Please update the code here. Add the check for null too. f.listFiles() will be null if there are no files in the directory.

Comment: @greenapps: Edited...I have some redundant checks and the code is not very clean right now, so don't mind that.

Comment: `if(files == null)` then you should return! Don't continue with the rest of your code.You could not only Log it but also display a Toast for the user before returning.  Please add the return statement. You use f.list() and f.listFiles(). That is not needed ofcourse. Just use one.

Comment: `if(files == null) Log.i("MyActivity","f.listFiles() failed!!!");`. Better: if(files == null) { Log.i("MyActivity", f.getAbsolutePath() + " does not contain files"); Toast(.., f.getAbsolutePath() + " does not contain files", .....); return;}

Comment: `if(f.isDirectory()) Log.i("MyActivity", "Directory exists");`. Not correct. Better: if(f.isDirectory() && f.exists() ) Log.i("MyActivity",  f.getAbsolutePath() + " directory exists");

Comment: So you should add also: `if ( !f.exists()) {Log.d(....); Toast(.....); return;}`. Do it before you try to list files in it.

Comment: @greenapps: I changed the if conditions as you said and am also returning in case of check failure. I am adding the logcat output too.I have left the redundant check for now. Like i said the code is very crude right now, my primary focus is to get it to work, and I'm still not able to do that

Comment: I really advise you to add the `if ( !f.exists()) {Log.d(....); Toast(.....); return;}` statements BEFORE you try to listFiles() the files. And even before that: `if ( !f.isDirestory()){Log.e(...); Toast(...) return;}` (Check first isDirectory then exists() and then list()). Well you see: the "Music" directory is empty.

Comment: @greenapps: It's not empty. I tried hardcoding the file names with path and it worked fine. It's only when I try using listFiles() that it fails.

Comment: Please give an example of such a hardcoded path.

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Music/"` that should be: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Music"`.

Comment: @greenapps: Added the working code with hardcoded values for paths

Comment: I see no errors in your code (execpt for the things i asked you to add/change but didn't). Your code should work. Don't understand.

Comment: Your code should work even without requesting permissions to read/write external storage. Did you?  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`.

Comment: @greenapps: turns out i had to add read_external_storage...fixed now...thanks for your help